# AJAX process with field validation

Tags: php, ajax

Whole AJAX code:

```
function checkEmail() {
  // var myForm = $("#mainForm").serialize();
  var fname = $("#first").val();
  var lname = $("#second").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var repass = $("#en").val();
  if(fname && lname && email && password && repass) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "connection.php",
      data: {
          fname:fname,
          lname:lname,
          email:email,
          password:password,
          repass:repass
      },
      type: "POST",
      success:function(data){
  $("#emailExists").show();
  $("#email").css("border","2px solid green");
  $("#no").css("visibility","hidden");
  $("#yes").css("visibility","visible");
  if(data){
    $("#email").css("border", "2px solid red");
    $("#no").css("visibility","visible");
    $("#yes").css("visibility","hidden");
    }else
    {
    $("#email").css("border", "2px solid green");
    $("#no").css("visibility","hidden");
    $("#yes").css("visibility","visible");
    window.location.href = 'home.php';
    }
  $("#emailExists").html(data);
  },
  error:function (){
  }
  });
   }
}
```

Here's a signup form validation, and an email exists system using PHP and AJAX. I have a problem with AJAX. So, on the click of the signup button, the AJAX should only run (to check if email already exists using PHP data and display error message) if every field is filled up, and if the password length is greater than or equal to 6 AND if the password is equal to the repass (re-enter password).

So, initially, in the success function, I wrote:

```
if(fname && lname && email && password && repass) {
```

And all the code under it. But it should also only call success function, if password value is greater than or equal to 6, and also if password is equal to repass. And if only every field is filled up AND password >= 6 and password == repass, it should take the user to the homepage (home.php), otherwise it should stay there, display error messages, then user will change to the correct details and it'll redirect to homepage. (I already have a window.location.href = 'home.php' in the else statement, so that's taken care of).

So for that I'm trying this code:

```
if(fname && lname && email && password && repass && password.val() >= 6 && password == repass) {
```

But it isn't working. What should I do? Please give a solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For every `if` there’s an `else`. When the former fails a test, in the latter you can, for debugging purposes, individually test each of those conditions. Either use `debugger`, `console.log`, or just `alert`

Answer (score -1):

As said [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length), use this:

```js
password.length >= 6
```

So:

```js
var password = $("#password").val();
if (fname && lname && email && password && repass && password.length >= 6 && password == repass) {
```

But form validation is more than just checking if it's filled or password length. You can use [RegEx](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to validate some objects.

Comment: Hey it's working, but if everything is correct, it's not redirecting to homepage.

Comment: How can that work? `password` is a string, so `.val()` on it will throw an error. It should just be `password.length`

Comment: You're right. I didn't read the full question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey Magnus. Thanks for that. However, you're answer as well doesn't seem to work. I checked the console and network, but nothing is there. And the information is not getting inserted into the database as well. Previously, it would redirect to the homepage as well, but now, it doesn't.

Comment: This code isn't working: if (fname && lname && email && password && repass && password.length >= 6 >= 6 && password == repass) {

Comment: False alarm. It's working. There were two ">= 6". Silly mistake. Sorry about that guys! Thanks for the help.